# Rsyslog in not logging due to Selinux, is my workaround ok

Tags: centos, selinux, rsyslog

I have these two parameters in /etc/rsyslog.conf

```
$ModLoad imjournal # provides access to the systemd journal
...
# Turn off message reception via local log socket;
# local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
$OmitLocalLogging on
```

I got problems with SELinux, Rsyslog logged this:

```
Jun  6 10:53:14 vpod1-logm-front-3 rsyslogd: fopen() failed: 'Permission denied', path: '/var/spool/imjournal.state.tmp'  [v8.24.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2013 ]
```

I had to add a new policy (generated by audit2alow)

```
cat  >syslog-imjournal.te << EOF
module syslog-imjournal 1.0;

require {
        type syslogd_t;
        type var_spool_t;
        class dir { add_name remove_name write };
        class file { create rename unlink write };
}

#============= syslogd_t ==============

allow syslogd_t var_spool_t:dir write;
allow syslogd_t var_spool_t:dir { add_name remove_name };
allow syslogd_t var_spool_t:file { create rename unlink write };
EOF

checkmodule  -m -o syslog-imjournal.m syslog-imjournal.te
semodule_package --module syslog-imjournal.m --outfile syslog-imjournal.pp
semodule --install=syslog-imjournal.pp --priority=400
```

I don't know if it is secure to do this, is there a better way?

Comment: If you downvote this question could you please tell me why so I can ask a better question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are storing the “imjournal.state” file in the wrong location, so SELinux is blocking writes.  Rather than creating a custom policy module that grants too much permissions, you should use the default location, which is /var/lib/rsyslog. The default config says:

```
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state
```

Comment: The `rsyslog.conf` had that lines.  I found that someone put a conf in /etc/rsyslog.d/ with `$WorkDirectory /var/spool`. I suppose that it was some deployment with a wrong target. Although I dont understand where they took to use that directory. Thank you to remember me the basics and taking the time to answer that question (which I realize was a really malformed question).